# Spring Batch - How to make parallel steps with one reads out of other step's writer?

Tags: java, spring, parallel-processing, spring-batch

I am quite new to the Spring batch framework.

I have created 2 steps within one job (let's call them **Step1** & **Step2**). I want to run them in **parallel**. Not only that, but **Step2's IteamReader** should use the **Step1's ItemWriter**.

In other words, Step2's ItemReader should wait for Step1's ItemWriter to write one chunk. As soon as Step1 writes, Steps2 starts reading & pass it on to its processor and further.

First question I have is that is it even possible to do that in Spring Batch? If yes, how?

And secondly, if that's not possible, what could be the work around?

Thanks.

Comment: in parallel? afaik, not possible, the steps follow the order you set in your configuration.

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/j-easy/easy-batch as an alternative?

Comment: @questionare it doesn't seem to provide the feature I am looking for.

Comment: @Stultuske no way to make it work?

Comment: @gohil90 not that I would know of.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can sort of hack it using a `<split/>` to run 2 steps at once. Step 1 would write to a queue which Step 2 can read from. The key here will be to make sure your Step 2's reader has a decent timeout on the `MessageConsumer` so it can wait long enough for Step 1 to write a chunk to the queue.

```
<split id="splitStep" task-executor="asyncTaskExecutor" >
    <flow>
        Step 1: reader -> processor -> writer (to queue)
    </flow>
    <flow>
        Step 2: reader (from queue) -> processor -> final writer
    </flow>
</split>
```

That said, is there a reason why you can't just use a composite processor?

```
 Step 1: reader -> processor 1 -> processor 2 -> writer
```

Or better yet, do you need to chunk this? It might be a better use case for Spring Integration or something.

And if you truly do need chunking, you could instead hack your reader to return a `List` and then use composite processors to chain your transformations of the entire chunk.

```
Reader: reads source, returns List<SourceItem>
Processor 1: List<SourceItem> in, perform transformations, List<TransformedItem> out
Processor 2: List<TransformedItem> in, additional transformations, List<FinalItem> out
Writer: List<List<FinalItem>> in, unpack the list, write to final destination
```

If you were to do this, you'd be circumventing how the framework typically works, so you'd need to set your commit-interval to 1 (because you only want the reader to return 1 list) and instead determine chunk size in your reader by changing the # of items in that list.

Comment: Can you please show me how to configure multiple processors in single step as you have mentioned above?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html#chainingItemProcessors

Comment: That helped me. I used your second approach.

Comment: Instead of reading and returning just one list, is splitting this one list into multiple smaller lists also a valid approach. This would then allow you to have a commit-interval above 1?

And do you have a reference explaining why spring Integration may be another way of implementing this?